# Is it possible to create an empty file using scp?

Tags: linux, scp

In *nix, I can create an empty file using cp:

```
cp /dev/null ~/emptyfile
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to do something similar using scp (instead of ssh + touch). If I try to run:

```
scp /dev/null remoteserver:~/emptyfile
```

it returns an error `/dev/null: not a regular file`

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, I don't wanna run any command at the remoteserver (i.e. No `ssh` command should be invoked).

So it's ok to run some command at localhost (echo, cat, dd or any other trivial command) and copy the resulting file to remoteserver.

It's preferable not leaving the resulting file at localhost. It's also good if the resulting command is an one-liner solution.

**EDIT2:**

It's impossible to use /dev/null approach as in `cp` command, because `scp` only works with regular files and directories:
https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/8a85f5458d1c802471ca899c97f89946f6666e61/scp.c#L838-L850

So it's mandatory to use another command (touch, cat, dd etc) to create a regular empty file (either in a previous command, pipe or a subshell).

Comment: Would the solution described here work for you? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189729/157965

Comment: @JohnMoon it doesn't. I need a solution that doesn't use ssh.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for your use case to create an empty file (`touch afilename`) and then send it to the remote host over scp (`scp afilename <remosthost>`)?

Comment: @willh99 yes, it would. Seems that all we can have is syntax sugar and alternatives to `touch` to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @willh99 [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522286/is-it-possible-to-create-an-empty-file-using-scp#comment93921504_53522286), creating an empty file locally, and then performing scp is the most feasible solution.

So far I came up with this:

```
filename=$(mktemp) && scp $filename remoteserver:~/emptyfile; rm $filename
```

It creates an empty file in a subshell, and copies it to remoteserver as `emptyfile`.

**Any refactor/improvements are welcome.**

**EDIT:** remove $filename whether scp succeeding or not, as stated by @Friek.

Comment: I wonder why you're micro-optimizing such a simple situation. Just stick with this, although I wouldn't use '&& rm $filename'. If the scp command fails, the temp file will still be left behind.

Comment: @Friek good point, I may use '|| rm $filename' instead. Well, micro-optimizin will never give me the simplicity of `cp /dev/null emptyfile` :-(

Comment: Using || rm .. will only delete the file if scp actually fails. Use ; instead.

Comment: oops, that's true.

Answer (score -1):

If you're just trying to create an empty file, you can use ssh and run the `touch` command like this:

`ssh username@remoteserver touch anemptyfile`

Comment: The question explicitly says instead of ssh + touch

Comment: yep, I know there are other command combinations that you may use in a real life, but I'm limited to use scp.

Comment: It's possible to have scp and/or sftp access without the ability to run arbitrary commands. Or the remote system may not be a unix system.

Comment: It's always good do remember that `touch` is not intended to create an empty file. If `anemptyfile` already exists with some content, `touch` will just update its timestamps and leave its contents untouched.